# Запуск php скрипта без запуска страницы

Tags: php, mysql

Как можно запустить, например, `update` sql базы без запуска страницы в определённое время?

Это возможно или искать альтернативы в js или чём-то другом?

Comment: Как насчет Cron? Установить таймер и он сам будет запускать скрипт в определенное время.

Answer (score 2):

Поставить задачу в Cron с любым необходимым графиком запуска скрипта.